# ERROR at line 2: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

Tags: sql, oracle, create-table, identity-column

Im getting this error and I need your help:

> ERROR at line 2: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

```
CREATE TABLE users(
    user_id int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    user_name varchar2(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    user_password varchar2(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    f_name varchar2(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    l_name varchar2(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    signature text NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    link varchar2(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    category_id int NOT NULL DEFAULT 1
);
```

Comment: you had extra *,*  **category_id int NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,**

Comment: Thanks, but I still get the same error...

Comment: What version of Oracle are you using?  `IDENTITY(1,1)` isn't valid in any version.  But you can at least define an identity column in 12.1.  `text` is not a valid data type.  And the empty string and `NULL` are not distinct things so it makes no sense to declare a column `NOT NULL` and then try to default it to `NULL` via the empty string.

Comment: Okay, i fixed the text valid type. Im using 10.2.0.4.0.

Comment: @JustinCave: I believe you got them all; that should be an answer :)

Comment: How do I do the Identity in an earlier version of oracle than?

Comment: @ZACHCALLOWAY Like this http://lalitkumarb.wordpress.com/2015/01/20/auto-increment-primary-key-in-pre-12c-releases-identity-functionality/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> NOT NULL DEFAULT ''

**`''`** is an empty string, which is considered as **NULL** in Oracle. So, makes no sense to have **NOT NULL** constraint but **defaulting** the value to **NULL** again. **It is contradicting!**

There are multiple issues with your table **DDL**. Create the table like this:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE users(
  2      user_id NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
  3      user_name VARCHAR2(100) DEFAULT 'default' NOT NULL,
  4      user_password VARCHAR2(100) DEFAULT 'default' NOT NULL,
  5      f_name VARCHAR2(50) DEFAULT 'default' NOT NULL,
  6      l_name VARCHAR2(50) DEFAULT 'default' NOT NULL,
  7      signature VARCHAR2(255) DEFAULT 'default' NOT NULL,
  8      LINK VARCHAR2(255) DEFAULT 'default' NOT NULL,
  9      category_id NUMBER DEFAULT 1  NOT NULL
 10  );

Table created.

SQL>
```

A note about [Identity column](http://lalitkumarb.wordpress.com/2015/01/20/identity-column-autoincrement-functionality-in-oracle-12c/). Since you are on version **10g**, Identity column is not supported. It was introduced in **12c**.

So, you need to explicitly use sequences. You could use the old **trigger-sequence** approach in your application to populate the primary key. Have a look at the demonstration for example and usage here http://lalitkumarb.wordpress.com/2015/01/20/auto-increment-primary-key-in-pre-12c-releases-identity-functionality/

For example,

**TABLE**

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE t (
  2    ID           NUMBER(10)    NOT NULL,
  3    text  VARCHAR2(50)  NOT NULL);
Table created.
SQL>
```

**PRIMARY KEY** to be populated by the **sequence**

```
SQL> ALTER TABLE t ADD (
  2    CONSTRAINT id_pk PRIMARY KEY (ID));
Table altered.
SQL>
```

**SEQUENCE** to support the primary key

```
SQL> CREATE SEQUENCE t_seq
  2  START WITH 1000
  3  INCREMENT BY 1;
Sequence created.
SQL>
```

**TRIGGER**

If you do not want to have the sequence in the **INSERT** , you could automate it via TRIGGER.

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER t_trg
  2  BEFORE INSERT ON t
  3  FOR EACH ROW
  4  WHEN (new.id IS NULL)
  5  BEGIN
  6    SELECT t_seq.NEXTVAL
  7    INTO   :new.id
  8    FROM   dual;
  9  END;
 10  /

Trigger created.

SQL>
```

**INSERT**

```
SQL> INSERT INTO t(text) VALUES('auto-increment test 1');

1 row created.

SQL> INSERT INTO t(text) VALUES('auto-increment test 2');

1 row created.

SQL>
```

Let’s see if we have the ID column auto-incremented with the desired values-

```
SQL> SELECT * FROM t;

   ID TEXT
----- --------------------------------------------------
 1000 auto-increment test 1
 1001 auto-increment test 2

SQL>
```

So, the ID column now starts with value 1000 and increments by 1 with subsequent inserts.

Answer (score 0):

1. There is no `text` datatype in oracle.
2. There is no `IDENTITY` modifier in ORACLE before Oracle 12c. If you are using Oracle 12c use this

   ```
   CREATE TABLE users(
           user_id NUMBER GENERATED BY DEFAULT ON NULL AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
           user_name varchar2(100) NULL DEFAULT '',
           user_password varchar2(100) NULL DEFAULT '',
           f_name varchar2(50) NULL DEFAULT '',
           l_name varchar2(50) NULL DEFAULT '',
           signature clob NULL DEFAULT '',
           link varchar2(255) NULL DEFAULT '',
           category_id int NULL DEFAULT 1
       );
   ```

More : [Oracle IDENTITY](http://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/identity-columns-in-oracle-12cr1.php#identity-columns)

Comment: Also, I believe Oracle can't have `''`, all empty strings are nulled, no? `user_name VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL` is okay, `user_name VARCHAR2(100) DEFAULT ''` is okay, but you can't combine them because you are saying a default value is disallowed.

Answer (score 0):

i thought that you try to execute the sql script in oracle

```
CREATE TABLE users(
    user_id int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    user_name varchar2(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    user_password varchar2(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    f_name varchar2(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    l_name varchar2(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    signature text NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    link varchar2(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    category_id int NOT NULL DEFAULT 1
);
```

but we had to convert before it execute in oracle
changes include as follows

- replace int with number(38) or number
- text with either char(50) or varchar2(50)
- its better to add primary key to the in an alter statement
- you are using not null and you try to insert the empty string in the table, in my view this has to changed with some relevant value
- there will be no such type identity(1,1) upto oracle 11g but it has implemented in Oracle 12,instead of identity use [sequence](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/sequences.php) with before inserted trigger for auto increment to the column

Comment: There is no `identity` in Oracle.

Comment: identity is in Oracle 12

Comment: No it doesn't. Not with that syntax: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_7002.htm#SQLRF01402

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name please what i had done suggestions which was placed below the table query